# Can vinegar cause fat loss?

Tags: weight-loss, fat-loss

I keep hearing about vinegar being used for weight loss. There is at least one study to back this up.

Here's a link to the study: [Vinegar Intake Reduces Body Weight, Body Fat Mass, and Serum Triglyceride Levels in Obese Japanese Subjects](http://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/bbb/73/8/73_1837/_article)

Has anyone tried this or heard of other studies?

Comment: Could you summarize how the study claims vinegar would cause fat loss?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd never heard of this before, but I did find other studies to back it up. [This](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16321601) study from 2005 found that vinegar (and peanuts, if you're interested) decreases glycemic load (i.e. it slows down the entry of glucose into your system). This [other](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16015276) 2005 study replicated these findings, and found that vinegar also increases feelings of fullness.[This](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19917452) study from 2009 supports both of these findings (along with similar effects for cinnamon). An [older study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9630389) links these effects of vinegar to delayed gastric emptying (i.e. food sits around in your stomach for longer).

So, it sounds like vinegar supports weight loss by keeping you full for longer. Because it lowers glycemic load, it can probably also help decrease risk for obesity-related disease like diabetes and heart disease.

Comment: I didn't know that, interesting! :D

Comment: +1 - I hadn't ever heard that, either. I'm fascinated. Great job with the sources! Excellent answer.

Comment: No wonder I like eating vinegar by the tablespoon! (besides it just tastes yummy!)